# Why mongoose save() doesn't update existing document with default values which are a nested schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, save, default

I have the following schema mongoose:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const getRating = ({ maxScore }) => ({
  type: new Schema(
    {
      score: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
      },
      maxScore: {
        type: Number,
        default: function() {
          console.log('inside default')
          return maxScore
        }
      }
    },
    { _id: false }
  )
})

const BrandRating = new Schema(
  {
    varietyOfProducts: {
      overall: getRating({ maxScore: 18 }),
      userFeedback: getRating({ maxScore: 9 }),
      other: getRating({ maxScore: 9 })
    }
  { _id: false }

const Brand = new Schema({
  rating: {
    type: BrandRating,
    required: true
  },
  slug: String
)
```

I have already a lot of `Brand` documents in mongodb and now I need to `rating` object which is a nested schema with each field also being a nested schema with default values. So now I want to run over all `Brand` documents in the db and just save them so that the defaults are applied. However, they're not applied and I'm not sure what the problem is:

```js
    const [brand] = await Brand.find({ 'slug': 'test' })
    await brand.save()
    console.log('brand', brand) // doesn't have any of the new rating default values, logs { slug: 'test' }  
    // { slug: 'test' }
```

Also I'm not seeing that the `console.log` statement is even called inside `default` mongoose function.

Comment: Could you include the output of `console.log('brand', brand)` in the question?

Comment: Try setting `default: { varietyOfProducts: {} }` for `rating` in `Brand` schema

Comment: @thammada.ts how does this help me? `varietyOfProducts` if an object of objects with default fields.

Comment: Because `BrandRating` can be empty,  `varietyOfProducts` itself is not a required field, although the subfields are required.

Comment: @thammada.ts but the reason I define the defaults is that `varietyOfProducts` has the specific structure, not just an empty object. So I definitely don't want it to be initialized to an empty object.

Comment: You have to initialise as an empty object to trigger the default values of the subfields.

Comment: @thammada.ts this worked partly, but I also needed to set defaults on `varietyOfProducts` as well (`varietyOfProducts: {type: new Schema({ overall: getRating({ maxScore: 18 }),
      userFeedback: getRating({ maxScore: 9 }),
      other: getRating({ maxScore: 9 })  }), default: { overall: {}, userFeedback: {}, //...etc }}`) . This creates a document with `varietyOfProducts: {}`. So I guess I need to define default objects on a higher level. While this is an improvement it's still far from the intuition I had that I can define the defaults on the lowest level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help from `@thammada.ts` I finally figured out how to set defaults. The key takeaway is to set an empty object as the default on `BrandRating` schema and define the actual default on the lowest possible level that is inside `getRating`:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const getRating = ({ maxScore }) => ({
  type: new Schema(
    {
      score: {
        type: Number
      },
      maxScore: {
        type: Number
      }
    },
    { _id: false }
  ),
  default: {
    score: 0,
    maxScore
  }
})

const BrandRating = new Schema(
  {
    varietyOfProducts: {
      overall: getRating({ maxScore: 18 }),
      userFeedback: getRating({ maxScore: 9 }),
      other: getRating({ maxScore: 9 })
    }
  { _id: false }

const Brand = new Schema({
  rating: {
    type: BrandRating,
    required: true,
    default: {}
  },
  slug: String
)
```